# Distributional result in NIW model

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, chi-squared

Suppose

$$
\Sigma^{-1} \sim \text{Wishart}_p \left(\frac{\Sigma_0^{-1}}{d_0},d_0\right)
$$

That is $\Sigma$ has a inverse Wishart distribution.

Furthermore

$$
W \mid \Sigma \sim \operatorname{Wishart}_p(\Sigma, d)
$$

$$
Z \mid \Sigma \sim \mathcal{N}_p(0,\Sigma)
$$

and $W$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $\Sigma$.

I want to prove (or disprove) that 
$$
\frac{Z^T\Sigma^{-1}Z}{Z^T(W+\Sigma_0d_0)^{-1}Z} \sim \chi^2(d+d_0-p+1).
$$

I can show that the result holds in a few special cases:

**Special case 1: p=1**
When $p=1$ the Wishart distributions reduces to $\chi^2$ distributions:
$$\Sigma^{-1} \sim \frac{1}{d_0\Sigma_0}\chi^2(d_0)$$
$$ W \mid \Sigma \sim \Sigma\chi^2(d) $$
It now follows that

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{Z^T\Sigma^{-1}Z}{Z^T(W+\Sigma_0d_0)^{-1}Z} &= 
\frac{W+\Sigma_0d_0}{\Sigma} \\ &= \frac{W}{\Sigma} + \Sigma_0d_0\Sigma^{-1} \\ &\sim \chi^2(d+d_0)
\end{split}
$$

since $\frac{W}{\Sigma}\sim \chi^2(d)$ and is independent of $\Sigma_0d_0\Sigma^{-1} \sim \chi^2(d_0)$

**Special case 2: "$d_0 = 0$"** 
If $V \sim \operatorname{Wishart}(\Sigma, d)$ then
$$
\frac{1}{(V^{-1})_{ii}} \sim \frac{1}{(\Sigma^{-1})_{ii}}\chi^2(d-p+1)
$$
see [Inverse-Wishart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution).

Now for any fixed vector $a$ of length $p$. Take an orthogonal matrix $B=\{b_{(1)},\ldots ,b_{(p-1)},\frac{a}{|a|}\}$. Then $B^TV^{-1}B \sim \text{Wishart}(B^T\Sigma^{-1}B,d)$. We now have
$$
\begin{split}
(B^TVB)^{-1} &= B^{-1}V^{-1}B^{T-1} = B^TV^{-1}B \\
(B^T\Sigma B)^{-1} &= B^T\Sigma^{-1}B \\
(B^T\Sigma^{-1}B)_{pp} &= \frac{1}{|a|^2}a^T\Sigma^{-1}a \\
(B^TV^{-1}B)_{pp} &= \frac{1}{|a|^2}a^TV^{-1}a
\end{split}
$$
Using the above result we have that for any $a$
$$
\frac{Z^T\Sigma^{-1}Z}{Z^TW^{-1}Z} \mid Z = a \sim \chi^2(d-p+1).
$$
Since the conditional distribution does not depend on $a$ it holds unconditionally as well.